# How to change mapbox marker, my current marker is a point?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

Here is my code snippet from my script. i want to change it to a car image or a pin marker any idea how to change it i tried to change it multiple times but i didnt work. [i want this marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGzW9.png)

```
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.Navigation());
function pointOnCircle(angle) {
return {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [long, lat]
};
}

map.on('load', function () {
// Add a source and layer displaying a point which will be animated in a circle.
map.addSource('point', {
    "type": "geojson",
    "data": pointOnCircle(0)
});

map.addLayer({
    "id": "point",
    "source": "point",
    "type": "circle",
    "paint": {
        "circle-radius": 10,
        "circle-color": "#FF0000"
    }
    "icon": "../assets/blue-marker.png"
});

function animateMarker(timestamp) {
    // Update the data to a new position based on the animation timestamp. The
    // divisor in the expression `timestamp / 1000` controls the animation speed.
    map.getSource('point').setData(pointOnCircle(timestamp /800));

    // Request the next frame of the animation.
    requestAnimationFrame(animateMarker);

}
// Start the animation.
animateMarker(0);
```